# A word which describes 'purposefully doing something differently to hide inability of doing it in the originally intended way'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes 'purposefully doing something different to hide inability of doing it in the originally intended ('better'/'harder') way'.

An example might be where you are trying to do a woodworking project without any visible screws. Then you had to use a screw in one joint because you weren't able to do it without any. You decide to use screws everywhere to make them more of an aesthetic feature and hide the fact that the first screw was not intended to be there.

An example sentence for the word: "I was trying to do the woodworking project without any visible screws, but XXX-ed and used screws everywhere instead."

The word would have a negative connotation to it.

"Settling" would come to mind, but does not imply the intend to hide inability.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any formal word or phrase, but **bodge** is one possibility in the sense of [this definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bodge). Several other online sources give slightly different definitions, mostly concerned with a bad repair.
I believe the word comes from the craft called "bodger" who were (strangely) highly skilled woodworkers in the UK furniture industry who, as outworkers, hand made individual parts (legs or seats of chairs for example) and sold them into factories for assembly into the finished article.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I agree that it would fit the sentence. But reading the definition, I'm still somewhat missing the part of ' purposefully hiding the inability to do better'.

Comment: Bodge frequently implies the inability or disinclination to do a proper job, but I don't think you'll get a word with the precise, specific nuance the OP wants.

Comment: I've heard 'playing off a false note' (applied to Hendrix, apparently), but can't find corroboration, so probably not a fixed expression.

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word, but an expression comes to mind:

> When life hands you lemons, make lemonade.

and there's another, whose general-purpose meaning is something like "there's a simple solution staring you in the face"

> The way out is through the door.

So you could say "I took the easy way out", which is actually something of a fixed phrase.

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't exactly explain why a problem happened in the first place, **overcorrect** is a fitting word to use here. According to [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overcorrect):

> to make too much of a correction: to adjust too much in attempting to offset an error, miscalculation, or problem.

Answer (score 0):

**deflect** (v.i.)

> II.5 To turn to one side or from a straight line; to change its
> direction; to deviate from its course.
>
> II.6 *figurative*
> **1879** The points where this type deflects from the truly humane ideal. M. Arnold, *Equality* in *Mixed Essays* 81
> OED online

> To cause something to change direction, or to suddenly go in a
> different direction
> *fig*. *The mayor deflected (= did not answer directly) questions about his political plans.*
>
> *Making wild allegations is what he does to deflect attention from his own problems.*  ([Politico](https://www.politico.com/story/2016/03/trump-corey-lewandowski-michelle-fields-221376))
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/deflect)

---

> As Ms. Harrison suggested, some of the remarks of white teachers were
> intended to **deflect** blame for school failure from teachers and the
> school onto children and families.
> [Amanda Lewis; *Race in the Schoolyard*](https://books.google.com/books?id=YQN3O-HKgesC&pg=PA64&dq=to%20deflect%20blame%20from%20inability&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUr5e-8bmDAxUGF2IAHRHhCoYQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=to%20deflect%20blame%20from%20inability&f=false) (2003)

> "You got what you wanted." Troy said nothing as I went on. "Longer
> hours, more shifts. Why don't you leave her alone? Are you trying to
> **deflect** from anyone noticing what a shitty waiter your are?
> [Stephanie Rose; *Safeguard*](https://books.google.com/books?id=w20vEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT193&dq=%22to%20deflect%22%20anyone%20from%20noticing&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2_Kbl8rmDAxUBEmIAHTn4DoUQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=%22to%20deflect%22%20anyone%20from%20noticing&f=false) (2021)

Answer (score -1):

**To chicken out:**

OED

> **1**. intransitive. *to chicken out*: **to withdraw from an undertaking because of fear or lack of courage; to fail to act on account of these.** *Also with of or on, specifying the undertaking or activity.*

> 1994   Observer (Nexis) 16 Oct. 13   *What a shame he chickened out of compulsory ID cards for all.*
>
> 2017   @dallas_vandyk3 13 Jan. in twitter.com (O.E.D. Archive)    *My best friend and I are getting tattoos next week. Unless she chickens out again.*

The verb can also be used where there is a lack of confidence in one's abilities and there is a fear of failure.